# Chart.js: making chartArea smaller

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The labels in my dataset are really big and the actual area where the bars are drawn could be made smaller to accommodate that, but I can't figure out how to do that.

This shows what I'm talking about: https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-js-resize-chartarea-ygn9ig?file=/index.html

The labels are overflowing and I'd like that to not happen somehow.

Comment: How do you want it to be displayed ? cropped with `...` at the end ? in 2 lines ? smaller ? something else ?

Comment: well, ideally the chartArea smaller, as per the title

Comment: You prefer to see correctly the chart than the labels ?